# TypeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object is not callable

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to save a data frame to object storage:

```
print(type(saveDF))
<class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>
```

Then:

```
saveDF.write().option("header", "true").csv("pre-processed")
```

Results in:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-d20d6b31a2d4> in <module>()
      1 ----> saveDF.write().csv("pre-processed")

TypeError: 'DataFrameWriter' object is not callable
```

I've seen a number of other questions with this problem, but the questions are using a different approach to saving as a csv.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue was a simple fix.  Instead of this:

```
saveDF.write().option("header", "true").csv("pre-processed")
```

It should have been:

```
saveDF.write.option("header", "true").csv("pre-processed")
```

Comment: if DataFrameWriter object is returned by all of these methods then why "write" works. I understand why "write()" doesn't work - because DataFrameWriter object is getting created. But, what does dataframe.write return? Can someone explain why the option provided works?